# SFMC - Journey Builder - custom activity - Read Data extension in UI

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, custom-activity

We are developing a custom journey activity for a client - this first for us.

As part of the configuration of the activity in the UI - the client wants us to reach out to their system using a Key to fetch certain values to load in a drop down that the end user will be able to select from - this will dictate what the users can do and cannot do

For the sake of simplicity of use I would like that the client does not have to type(or copy paste) the key every time they wish to user the custom journey activity. What would be idea is for us to save the key/keys in a data extension in the client business unit and read the DE during design phase to auto populate the drop down in the UI. I would rather not save this in the web site configuration files as the client would like to extend this hosted activity to other business units and would prefer this to be in a private DE.

So far i have had success getting DE values on Execute if they are part of Contact builder attribute set but during design time i am lost.

Any pointers/directions on how we can achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to read a DE in the custom journey activity UI would be via the Postmonger event RequestToken. The journey builder in return fires the requestedTokens interface which contains a Marketing cloud legacy token and a fuel2 token. Now any DE can be queried using this token.